# Scala Library Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: scala, apple-push-notifications

i am searching a library to send Apple Push Notifications from Scala.

Does anyone has any experiences with a library written in Scala?

Or is javaPNS (https://code.google.com/p/javapns/) the best to choose?